# Extracting all repeating capturing groups

Tags: regex, validation, match, extract, regex-group

I'm having troubles with a Regex. I'm trying with the same one to validate and extract all repeating groups from the matched string.

Goal: I'm looking to validate and extract times for specific days and also the default time. My format is: `{def_time}[|{day}={time}]`

A few examples:

- 00:01:05
- 23:50|Mon=23:00|Thu=23:00
- 23:50|Mon=23:00:55|Thu=23:00|Sun=23:00:10

I came up first with this Regex:

```
/^(\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)(\|(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)=(\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?))*$/i
```

It works great to validate, extract the default time, but only captures the last repeating group.
Is there a way to have all these repeated groups captured?

I also tried (with g option):

```
/(?:^|\|(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)=)(\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)/gi
```

It will extract all groups but doesn't validate the whole string to match.

Answer (score 1):

A repeated capturing group will capture the last iteration only, cos it overides the group with each finding. So you will have to use these both regexes, first to validate and then to capture.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for confirming though.